# Complication in accessing Object's value in D3 V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I hope my question isn't too hard to understand. After I using the nest() function to my data and assigned to **var groupByAgeAndtime**, I have difficulties in accessing the values of the object. I don't know how to access the object's value directly and pass the value to d3.forceSimulation.

I've tried using `Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime, function(d){ return groupByAgeAndTime[d];})` to access object's value but it didn't work.

Here's the issue:

```
var groupByAgeAndtime = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d) { return d.age; })
              //.key(function(d) { return d.time_in_hospital; })
              .rollup(function(v) {
                return{
                    mean_time_in_hospital : d3.mean(v, function(d){ return d.time_in_hospital;})

              } })
              .object(datapoints);
```

After nesting and rollup the data, I don't know how to access and pass the **var** **groupByAgeAndtime** to another variable's function:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("x",d3.forceX(width/2).strength(0.05))
    .force("y",d3.forceY(height/2).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d){
        return radiusScale(d.groupByAgeAndtime) + 2;
    }))
```

How should I pass the nested data to `return radiusScale(d.groupByAgeAndtime) + 2;` then?

Here is my code in fiddle: [code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james_bond100/6b8ka5Lt/1/)

I would really appreciate if some expert are able to answer my problem.

Comment: ***I hope my asnwer isn't too hard to understand***, You mean your question, well it will be easier if you post the object structure and what value are you trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transform the `d3.nest` data back into an array of key-value pairs

```
d3.map(datapoints).entries();
```

You have to do the sorting yourself and be aware that the key is a string with a possible `$`.